# NullPointerException Error when trying to set javafx TextField text from JnativeHook mouse events

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception, jnativehook

I am trying to set javafx TextField text when JnativeHook MoseClicked event  happens.But i face with "NullPointerException" error.I put my Controller class code in here:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable, NativeMouseListener {

@FXML
private TextField txt_Search;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

   txt_Search.setText("dvdf"); //this is work and no problem is in here
           Listener();
}
public void Listener() {
    // Clear previous logging configurations.
    LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
    // Get the logger for "org.jnativehook" and set the level to off.
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
    logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);
    try {
        GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
    } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
        System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
        System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

        System.exit(1);
    }
    // Construct the example object.
    FXMLDocumentController example = new FXMLDocumentController();
    // Add the appropriate listeners.
    GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(example);
}

 @Override
public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent nme) {
    if (nme.getClickCount() == 2) {
        System.out.println("Double Click Event");
        txt_Search.setText("Mouse clicked");
    }

}

@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent nme) {
    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent nme) {
    //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}
```

}

And this error is occurring :

> Double Click Event
>   Exception in thread "JNativeHook Dispatch Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at FXMLDocumentController.nativeMouseClicked(FXMLDocumentController.java:60)
>   at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$EventDispatchTask.processButtonEvent(Unknown Source)
>   at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$EventDispatchTask.processButtonEvent(Unknown Source)
>   at org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen$EventDispatchTask.run(Unknown Source)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

**Update:**

> I update my code and annotate txt_Search with @FXML annotation

Comment: Looks like `txt_Search` is null when you try to use it.

Comment: I don't want to read field value. While when I want to set text  to txt_Search  in the initialize method do not problem.Only in  outside of initialize method this error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

@Kingtak you never initialized your 'txt_Search' variable.You can use @FXML annotation here and in fxml file assign the id to the textfield there.

Comment: the txt_Search  is fx:id of textField.I add @FXML annotation.But the problem is not solved

Comment: I do not think the problem in the field txt_Search . The problem is  just outside the initialize method.

Answer (score 0):

You should go back and review the [working with swing](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Usage#working-with-swing) section of the usage wiki.  The events produced by this library **do not** operate on the Swing event dispatch thread by default!  You must wrap access to swing components OR use `GlobalScreen.setEventDispatcher(new SwingDispatchService());` before registering the hook.  For more information, please read about the [event dispatch thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and [Swing thread safety](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Is similar solution for javafx.I don't want to  use Swing componnets

Comment: Can you let me know what the solution for JavaFX is so I can add a note to the Wiki?